How to establish debug mode in local Eclipse when the application is running on a different server?
I have provided the appropriate details (IP address and port number) of the server where my application is running in the Remote Java Application. However, my eclipse is installed in my local. When I try to start debug, it says VM can't connect.
For reference -
My local IP (where Eclipse is present) - 192.x.x.49
IP of the server where my targeted application is installed - 10.x.x.25
The version of Eclipse I am using is - Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Is it possible to debug in local eclipse when the application instance is present in a different server box?
Thank you!
I have input the IP address and port number of the server in Remote Java Application details along with Socket Attach selected.

The IP-addresses you use strongly indicate that the application is running somewhere where it might require additional configuration to work. You may want to provide additional details.

thank you for your response. Additional details like?
In Remote Java Application, I have provided the connection type as Standard (Socket Attach), IP and port number.
What other configurations must be added? and where?

Are you using docker?  If not you must talk to your network manager. If yes, you need to configure docker to allow this.

Yes, eclipse can remote-debug. You'll need to do quite a bit of setup. Think about it: If I can hook up a debugger to your running application, I completely own it. I can see all memory, modify whatever I want. I can log in as admin, see admins log in and see their password, I can make your server rack up massive IAAS bills. I can use it as a platform to launch my hacks and get you on the hook for the legal repercussions. Hence, you can't 'just' hook up to an external server. An easy way to do it, is to tunnel it all through SSH.

Are you running the server in the way needed for it to listen to incoming connections from a debugger? The port number won't be the same one clients use to connect to the server.
